# unable to get the hidden value on button clicked

Tags: php

i m using isset to get the button value clicked using hidden type...below is my code

```
<form id="posform" name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="1" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="2" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="3" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="4" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['updatepos'])){
$targetbtnvalue=$_POST['updatepos'];
echo $targetbtnvalue;
}
```

but with below code irrespective of the button clicked it always echos the last button value i.e 4.

i am trying to get it to echo the corresponding value of button clicked...plz guide

Comment: I believe each button needs a separate `form` tag.

Comment: @Richard is correct. Clicking ANY of those buttons will submit the same form of hidden inputs. You either need to wrap each hidden input and button in its own form element... OR use javascript to submit only the value you wish based on which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's the same form with the same field.

Try this instead:

```
<form name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
   <div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="1" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>
<form name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
    <div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="2" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>
<form name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
    <div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="3" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>
<form name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
    <div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos" value="4" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. It just won't work as expected, but will not throw any errors. Only the last field will have the "true" ID.

Comment: It's entirely true. It's invalid HTML. Try validating it.

Comment: It may be invalid, but the browser will render anyway.

Comment: Never said it wouldn't render but it's poor practice to do so

Answer (score 0):

All of your hidden input names are same i.e **updatepos** which shouldn't be. So you can try with different names for hidden inputs or make it array like this way `updatepos[]`. Then you'll get all the hidden input values on your `$_POST` array not just the last one.

```
form id="posform" name="posform" action="" method="POST"  >
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos[]" value="1" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos[]" value="2" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos[]" value="3" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="updatepos[]" value="4" /><input type="submit" value="Update" ></div>
</form>
```

and then with PHP try like this,

```
if (isset($_POST['updatepos'])){
    $targetbtnvalue=$_POST['updatepos'];
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($targetbtnvalue);
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: instead of print_r i am using echo and it outs as array instead of the value